# Parsing strings from command line input, moving into array

Tags: c

I'm trying to take an input of characters, break them up into strings using non-alphabetic characters as delimiters, and move those strings into their own array. I can't seem to get a working implementation of this block of code and its rather frustrating. Any help is appreciated.

```
char *ptr = strtok(arg1, " "); //pointer to the first token delimited by a space.
int i=0;
while (ptr != NULL) { //separate all the tokens and move each into the tokens array
    new_num_tokens++;

    if(new_num_tokens == num_tokens) { //need to allocate more memory
        num_tokens += 2;
        char *tmp = (char *)realloc(tokens, (num_tokens+1) * sizeof(char)); //num_tokens+1 for the null character
        if(!tmp) {
            printf("Could not reallocate memory");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        } else {
            tokens = tmp;
        }
    }
    strcpy(&tokens[i], ptr);

    ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
    i+=sizeof(char);
}
```

Not shown is code that iterates through the entire input and replaces all non-alphabetic with spaces. I'm incrementing the number of tokens by two to simulate increasing the array by 2.

Comment: What does "break them up into strings using non-alphabetic characters as delimiters" mean? You are only looking for a space delimiter. Also, the memory reallocation isn't taking any account of the length of the token isolated by `strtok`, only  the number of tokens found.

Comment: you have a few issues. I would suggest some simpler code to start out. But one issue is that you want tokens to be a list of pointers but you are allocating sizeof(char) not sizeof(char*). ie-you are making a list of bytes instead of pointers.

Comment: Your code that replaces non-alpha characters with blanks should be changed to recognize the non-alpha as the end of a "word" — you can use that to split the string as you go, instead of making two passes over it.  You should devise code that allows you to add a string to an allocated list of pointers, increasing the size of the list when needed.  You've not got that part right yet — which complicates your life.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by converting my `char *tokens` array to a double pointer `char **tokens` as outlined below:

```
    char **tokens = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 2);
    char *p = arg1;
    for(; *p; p++) {
        if (!isalpha(*p)) *p = ' '; //replace every nonalpha character with a space so we can use space
                                    //as a delimiter in strtok()
    }

    char *ptr = strtok(arg1, " "); //pointer to the first token delimited by a space.
    int i=0;
    while (ptr != NULL) { //separate all the tokens and move each into the tokens array
        new_num_tokens++;

        if(new_num_tokens == num_tokens) { //need to allocate more memory
            num_tokens += 2;
            char **tmp = realloc(tokens, (num_tokens+1) * sizeof(char *)); //num_tokens+1 for the null character
            if(!tmp) {
                printf("Could not reallocate memory");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            } else {
                tokens = tmp;
            }
        }
        tokens[i] = ptr;

        ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
        i++;
    }
```